# Like to select one row in a table to edit in dialogue but keep selecting last one, edit works but only for the last one

Tags: reactjs, row, edit, react-table

Here is my code, received data from API but did take it out to make code work on sandbox, can maybe replace data if it would help. Would appreciate any help. https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-thunder-0ns6o?file=/src/App.js

```
<TableBody>
    {item.userBankAccount.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <TableRow hover key={index}>
          <TableCell>{item.bankName}</TableCell>
          <TableCell>{item.bankAddress}</TableCell>
          <TableCell>{item.bankAddress}</TableCell>
          <TableCell>{item.bankSwift}</TableCell>
          <TableCell>{item.accountName}</TableCell>
          <TableCell>{item.accountNo}</TableCell>
          <Dialog
            open={this.state.dialogueEditOpen}
            onClose={this.handleClose}
            aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
            index={index}
          >
            <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Edit Bank</DialogTitle>
            <DialogContent>
              <TextField
                label="Bank Name"
                name="bankName"
                onChange={e => this.onChangeUserBankAccount(e, index)}
                type="text"
                value={item.bankName}
                variant="outlined"
              />
              <TextField
                label="Bank Address"
                name="bankAddress"
                onChange={e => this.onChangeUserBankAccount(e, index)}
                type="text"
                value={item.bankAddress || ""}
                variant="outlined"
              />
              <TextField
                label="Bank Swift"
                name="bankSwift"
                onChange={e => this.onChangeUserBankAccount(e, index)}
                type="text"
                value={item.bankSwift || ""}
                variant="outlined"
              />

              <TextField
                label="Account Name"
                name="accountName"
                onChange={e => this.onChangeUserBankAccount(e, index)}
                type="text"
                value={item.accountName || ""}
                variant="outlined"
              />
              <TextField
                label="AccountAddress"
                name="accountAddress"
                onChange={e => this.onChangeUserBankAccount(e, index)}
                type="text"
                value={item.accountAddress || ""}
                variant="outlined"
              />
              <TextField
                label="AccountNo"
                name="accountNo"
                onChange={e => this.onChangeUserBankAccount(e, index)}
                type="text"
                value={item.accountNo || ""}
                variant="outlined"
              />
            </DialogContent>
            <DialogActions>
              <Button
                onClick={e => this.handleClose(e)}
                color="primary"
              >
                Cancel
              </Button>
              <Button
                onClick={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}
                color="primary"
              >
                Save Changes
              </Button>
            </DialogActions>
          </Dialog>
          <TableCell align="right">
            <IconButton onClick={e => this.handleOpenEdit(e, index)}>
              <SvgIcon fontSize="small">
                <EditIcon />
              </SvgIcon>
            </IconButton>

            <IconButton onClick={e => this.handleRemove(e, index)}>
              <SvgIcon fontSize="small">
                <Trash2 />
              </SvgIcon>
            </IconButton>
          </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is in the index ,just create a seprate state when clicking edit getting the array number and replaced then index with that ,onchange worked and was saving data on the right place.